# map fragment shows blank when app resumes from background to front. GL thread crash

Tags: here-api

I compiled a HERE tutorial app, "basic map solution", and installed it on Motorola XT1565(android 6.0.1). When I launch it, the map view can be shown, but if I move it to background and later bring it back to front, sometimes I see the map view is blank:  no map content. I caught the following GL thread crash error in the log.

I am using HERE Android SDK 3.1.1, and I can not find same issue on Here official app from Google Playstore. So I wonder if this issue is related to EGL lib compatible issue or there are some bugs in Here SDK native lib?

```
07-05 13:56:02.034 18468-18952/com.here.android.tutorial I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 166ada0, Ifd751822f5
                                                                   Build Date                       : 01/26/16
                                                                   OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
                                                                   Local Branch                     : AU12_SBA
                                                                   Remote Branch                    : 
                                                                   Remote Branch                    : 
                                                                   Reconstruct Branch               : 
07-05 13:56:02.185 18468-18952/com.here.android.tutorial I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-05 13:56:02.288 18468-2216/com.here.android.tutorial E/BaseTextureView: ******** GL Thread crash ********Thread[BaseTextureView-RenderThread,6,main]
07-05 13:56:02.391 18468-2216/com.here.android.tutorial W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: createWindowSurface failed EGL_BAD_CONFIG
07-05 13:56:02.392 18468-2216/com.here.android.tutorial W/System.err:     at com.nokia.maps.y$a.f(BaseTextureView.java:495)
07-05 13:56:02.392 18468-2216/com.here.android.tutorial W/System.err:     at com.nokia.maps.y$a.run(BaseTextureView.java:301)
07-05 13:56:02.392 18468-2216/com.here.android.tutorial E/BaseTextureView: ******** GL Thread crash ********Thread[BaseTextureView-RenderThread,6,main]
07-05 13:56:02.445 18468-2216/com.here.android.tutorial E/libEGL: eglDestroySurface:595 error 300d (EGL_BAD_SURFACE)
07-05 13:56:02.445 18468-2216/com.here.android.tutorial E/libEGL: eglDestroyContext:697 error 3006 (EGL_BAD_CONTEXT)
```

Comment: Please check with SDK 3.2 that was released last week, since this problem should be fixed with this version. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Marco, I rebuilt the test app with here 3.2 sdk, looks this issue happened less, but still can be reproduced. I went through the 3.2 release notes, don't find anything related to my issue.

Comment: I think the bugfix is not mentioned in the release notes explicitly. I'll add your information to our internal ticket so we can have a further look into it. Thanks.

Comment: We fixed a similar problem but for the Galaxy S7 in the SDK. We are investigating this issue now as soon as we can procure a device. One question, do you have developer options on to always destroy and re-create an activity ?

Comment: Hi David, in my development, I just need sometimes the here app can be put into background and later bring back to font. On this case, the activity don't be destroyed and recreated.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, didn't notice this.Under developer settings, did you enable destroy activities for testing? This maybe one cause of the crash.

Comment: @Marco i m using android premium sdk 3.2.1 and still face this issue sometime in J7 android version 6.0.1. Is this jniLibs issue or bug in sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Please check with SDK 4.x that was released last week, since this problem should be fixed with this version.