# Android Here map not resuming in Nougat (API 24)

Tags: here-api

I have followed HERE maps tutorial and created simple map app
https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android/topics/app-simple-android-studio.html

When my activity is resumed, the app sometimes doesnot load map. I have to close app and restart it for map engine (or whatever controls loading map inside map fragment) to load the tiles back again. Sometimes it works fine but when i zoom out to country level and go back to my city, i see this problem. I keep getting below error:

```
09-14 22:17:40.986 27447-27982/com.maps.apnawayz E/BaseTextureView: ******** GL Thread crash ********Thread[BaseTextureView-RenderThread,5,main]
09-14 22:17:40.988 27447-27982/com.maps.apnawayz W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: createWindowSurface failed EGL_BAD_CONFIG
09-14 22:17:40.988 27447-27982/com.maps.apnawayz W/System.err:     at com.here.android.mpa.internal.l$a.d(BaseTextureView.java:475)
09-14 22:17:40.988 27447-27982/com.maps.apnawayz W/System.err:     at com.here.android.mpa.internal.l$a.run(BaseTextureView.java:298)
09-14 22:17:40.988 27447-27982/com.maps.apnawayz E/BaseTextureView: ******** GL Thread crash ********Thread[BaseTextureView-RenderThread,5,main]
09-14 22:17:40.992 27447-27982/com.maps.apnawayz E/libEGL: eglDestroySurface:603 error 300d (EGL_BAD_SURFACE)
09-14 22:17:40.992 27447-27982/com.maps.apnawayz E/libEGL: eglDestroyContext:701 error 3006 (EGL_BAD_CONTEXT)
```

Could someone tell me how to avoid this.Looks like it only appears in API 24 (nexus 5X), it works fine in API 21(HTC one M7).
I am using android Nougat, Here starter sdk. 
I tried enabling destroy activity under development settings as suggested here but didnt help:
 [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232689/map-fragment-shows-blank-when-app-resumes-from-background-to-front-gl-thread-cr#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232689/map-fragment-shows-blank-when-app-resumes-from-background-to-front-gl-thread-cr#_=_)

Comment: I think we fixed this in the premium SDK. Perhaps we are missing a patch in the starter SDK too. Let me log a bug.

Comment: @DavidLeong Sometimes I am facing same problem in Android Premium SDK 3.2.1. My device android version is 6.0.1. Please help what to do to avoid this problem.

Comment: Can you provide which device you are experiencing this problem on?

Comment: @DavidLeong Samsung Galaxy J7. android version - 6.0.1

Comment: I do not have a J7 device, but I can ask if we can reproduce it on the set of devices we do have.

Comment: @DavidLeong is this jniLibs issue or bug in sdk? and currently i dont checked in other devices so will this issue appeared on other devices or not?

Comment: @Akash We do not know yet. At least with the devices we have we cannot reproduce it. It maybe a device specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

We have added many new updates to our Android and iOS SDKs and your issue is currently not reproducible.

Upgrade to the latest SDK and check out the documentation and code examples:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html

https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples